# Problem with pie-charts when exporting them to an image file

Tags: qgis, chart

I have 3 vector layers: a map of Europe and N.Africa, a line layer, and a point layer (on the top). I have created pie-charts over the points in QGIS 1.7.3, and on QGIS itself, they look fine. [image]

However, when I export them as image files using the Print Composer, I notice that they are all over the place (as you can see in the 2nd picture)[image]

This problem is also occurring in QGIS 1.8.0. Can you please tell me how I can fix this? Thanks.